# is not empty then' after foreach

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I am not good in smarty php so I would like to have advise on how to make a 'is not empty then' after foreach below:

```
{foreach from=$form_fields item=form_field}
{if $form_field.caption == "Language Name" || $form_field.caption == "Tool or Technology Name" || $form_field.caption == "Area, Field, or Speciality"}
```

CODE:

```
{elseif $complexField == "Languages" || $complexField == "Tool_Technology" || $complexField == "AreasOfExpertise"}
{foreach from=$complexElements key="complexElementKey" item="complexElementItem"}
       <div class="row-fluid">
     {foreach from=$form_fields item=form_field}
         {if $form_field.caption == "Language Name" || $form_field.caption == "Tool or Technology Name" || $form_field.caption == "Area, Field, or Speciality"}

           <h4>{display property=$form_field.id complexParent=$complexField complexStep=$complexElementKey}&nbsp;</h4>{else}
   <div style="display:inline">
      <label class="span4" for="slider">[[$form_field.caption]]</label>
      <div class="span8"> 
    <div class="progress progress-info progress-striped" style="margin-bottom: 9px;" rel="tooltip" title="{display property=$form_field.id complexParent=$complexField complexStep=$complexElementKey}%">
    <div class="bar" style="width: {display property=$form_field.id complexParent=$complexField complexStep=$complexElementKey}%;"></div>
    </div>
       </div>
   </div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</div>
{/foreach}
```

ID    l              Caption        l          Type

KeySkills   l        Key Skills          l         complex

Tool_Technology l   Tool & Technology   l      complex

<< Tool & Technology >>

ToolorTechnologyName l Tool or Technology Name l   string

Proficiency     l       Proficiency         l          integer

Comment: you mean `{if $form_field.caption != ''} {$form_field.caption} {/if}`?

Comment: you mean `{if not empty($form_field.caption)} {$form_field.caption} {/if}?`

Comment: Sorry for not giving useful information. Definitely not $form_field.caption because it is caption name for records.Empty or not will still make the foreach loop. Not $form_field.id too. How to make foreach not loop if there is no record or value? –

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
{if $form_field.caption neq ""} 
//your code
{else}
// else part
{/if}
```